# Why does InternetReadFile not grab the whole source of the website?

Tags: c++, wininet

So i am coding a project with WinInet.h library with win32 and I am using string comparisons to check whether a certain string is in the source code except InternetReadFile isn't grabbing the entire source code, it only grabs the top like 20%, i tried increasing the NumberOfBytes parameter and I increased it to 10 million and now it just takes forever. Basically, i have a program that you click a button and it grabs the source code and displays it in a messagebox. I am trying to make it so that when you click the button, it searches through the source code for the specific strings displays a message box saying the text was found.

Anyone know what i can do?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

> **”** The amount of data to be read for each call to `InternetReadFile` is specified by the `dwNumberOfBytesToRead` parameter and the data is returned in the `lpBuffer` parameter. A normal read retrieves the specified dwNumberOfBytesToRead for each call to `InternetReadFile` until the end of the file is reached. **To ensure all data is retrieved, an application must continue to call the `InternetReadFile` function until the function returns `TRUE` and the `lpdwNumberOfBytesRead` parameter equals zero.**

So you have to call `InternetReadFile()` in a loop until you have received all of the data you are expecting.  And since you are doing string searches, you need to buffer the read data and then scan the buffer, since the string you are looking for may come across in several pieces spanning across multiple `InternetReadFile()` calls.